# unresolved reference error in my RecyclerView code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-developer-api

setting RecyclerVeiw for the fragment_bottom_sheet.xml and setting the data,

[image: Here is the FragmentBottomSheet.kt code,]
[Here is the adapter Code MenuAdapter,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJHQz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJHQz.png)

In the First code of class MenuBottomSheetFragment,
I am supposed to get no error, but the menuRecyclerView is Marked red and showed unresolved reference.I googled and youtubed it but  no luck, stuck here for a long time any help will be a great favour.

binding.menuRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
binding.menuRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

the menuRecyclerView must appear while writing code but it is not recognising

Comment: in MenuBottomSheetFragment.xml check id menuRecyclerView

Comment: i mean recycler view id in MenuBottomSheetFragment.xml

Comment: thanks man you really helped me ,that's my Fault cause i am a beginner.

Comment: ok comment up arrow click